# Does a quadratic polynomial with a repeated rational root have "rational roots" (*plural*)?

Tags: terminology, roots, quadratics

From NYCIML (F18SA03):

> For how many ordered pairs of integers $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ does the equation $ax^2+bx+a=0$ have rational roots?

Would $(a,b)=(1,2)$ (corresponding to the equation $x^2+2x+1=0$, which has $-1$ as a repeated rational root) be considered a solution? That is, does a *repeated* root count as "roots" (*plural*)?

(The official solution doesn't consider.)

Comment: Yeah, from the statement of the problem and its restrictions (or lack thereof), I think $(a,b)=(1,2)$ is a solution here.

Comment: Generally in those types of questions, the plural is used in the sense of "does something like this exist", and the plural is used because it it is a priori unknown if there are $0$, $1$ or more. It's like answering "Did you meet any friends at the party?" with "Yes, Mike was there." and not "No, I only met 1 friend there".

Comment: That's really interesting. The official solution does not consider (1,2) as a solution.