# Domain of Real Roots of a Quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization, solution-verification, quadratics

The following MCQ(single correct option) is from ***JEE Main 2022***

> Let $S$ be the set of all integral values of $\alpha$ for which the sum of squares of two real roots of the quadratic equation $3x^2+(\alpha-6)x+(\alpha+3)=0$ is minimum. Then $S$:
>
> 1. Is an empty Set
> 2. Is a singleton
> 3. Contains exactly two elements
> 4. Contains more than two elements

This [solution](https://questions.examside.com/past-years/jee/question/plet-s-be-the-set-of-all-integral-values-of-alpha-for-jee-main-mathematics-trigonometric-functions-and-equations-hoj9wrjvbomqa0ll) uses the condition for the equation to have non-complex roots:
$$\text{Discriminant}\geq0\implies\alpha(\alpha-24)\geq0\implies(\alpha\leq0)\cup(\alpha\geq24)$$

If $a$ and $b$ are roots of the quadratic, the sum of squares using Vieta's formulas for the sum and product of roots:
$$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab=\frac{\alpha^2-18\alpha+18}{9}=f(\alpha)$$

The above quadratic is minimized at its vertex, $\alpha=\frac{-b}{2a}=9$, which is rejected since for this value the roots are not real.

[image]

**My Question:**
The function to be minimized is a quadratic with restricted domain, and hence it has a minimum at the left endpoint(see graph). Hence, the given solution is incorrect.

However, *two* real roots (as opposed to a real root, or repeated roots), means the roots must be distinct, which means the discrimant must be $>$, and not $\geq$. If you redo the solution using this constraint, the endpoints of the domain are not included, and hence there is no minimum for  values.

Hence, the solution arrives at the right answer, but needs to be corrected as above. Is my thought process correct?

Comment: I'll bet a lot of contestants answered "2".  From what I've seen of contest problems, one cannot assume that if a problem says "two real roots" that they _are_ distinct.  The sum of squares of real roots has the minimal value $ \ 2 \ $ for $ \ \alpha \ = \ 0 \ . \ $  The posted solution does indeed find that the minimum of the sum of squares of the zeroes occurs for $ \ \alpha \ = \ 9 \ $, but that sum is $ \ -7 \ $ and the zeroes are complex.  It doesn't seem to follow that that is what the problem is asking.  I find either the solution missing the point or the problem is misleadingly worded.

Comment: If they _do_ mean to have distinct real zeroes, then I'd agree with you that the function of the sum of squares of real zeroes has no minimum (as that has been _excluded_), so that would make "1" the correct choice.

Comment: Your comment is quite valid. Let try to identify what is the JEE default. What do they mean when they say two real roots. In the meantime, do you have examples of contest questions which say two real roots, and are ok with repeated roots.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172325/does-a-quadratic-polynomial-with-a-repeated-rational-root-have-rational-roots

Here is an example of a question where rational roots are implied to be distinct. This is what implicitly led me to conclude that two roots are meant to be distinct. (Ideally, the question should be precise and clarify).

Comment: I had to hunt for this under responses to my comments:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4501975/finding-a-and-b-for-the-given-polynomial#comment9450663_4501975  .  The problem asks for "all the roots" being non-negative; it is quite easy to answer if one considers the possibility that the zero has multiplicity $ \ 4 \ , \ $ and not at all simple if one believes there must be distinct zeroes.  Certainly questions should be specific about what it sought, but I've seen many problems where "traps are set" if particular possibilities are not considered.

Comment: I'm not _arguing_ with anything you've said -- I suspect there was a small riot when contestants were told the _official_ answer is choice "1" and objections were raised by them that the wording permits choice "2".  (I'd also bet there isn't a "default" phrasing.  Generally, people taking such exams need to be alert to the possibilities allowed in the problem statement, but posers of problems are not always careful about what those possibilities might be.  (Goodness knows I've seen enough trouble over the years caused by sloppy wording of exam writers...)